# Iterator inside of loop will not increment

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm attempting to compare two string arrays. Whenever I get to the while loop inside of the if statement, I get stuck in an infinite loop because even though I have an iterator inside of the loop, it doesn't increment. I have the `cout<< finder;` in the loop just to see what finder is at, and it never increments above zero. If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it.

```
if (memory[p] == "J")
    {
        if (is_number(memory[p+1]))
        {
            worker = atoi(memory[p+1].c_str());
            p = worker;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            int finder = 0;
            while (memory[p+1] != Symtablelab[finder])
            {
                cout << finder;
                finder = finder + 1;
            }

            if (memory[p+1] == Symtablelab[finder])
            {
                int k = Symtablepos[finder];
                worker = atoi(memory[k].c_str());

                p = worker;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would change it to `cout << "memory[p+1]:" << memory[p+1] <<  " Symtablelab[finder]:" << Symtablelab[finder] << " finder: " << finder;`. This way you can see if the loop ever gets executed more than once. What you need to do is to determine what your state is and if it's what you expect.

Comment: @PreetSangha When I do that, I get the correct string value for memory[p+1] and the correct string value for Symtablelab[0]. They are not equal to each other. Finder stays at zero and the loop just runs over and over because it never increments.

Comment: how many times `finder` gets printed in your loop?

Comment: Any chance that it is the outer loop (not shown in your post, but the presence of the continue statements suggest its presence) that is infinite-looping, rather than the inner one?  I don't see how the inner loop could be looping without having finder increment.

Comment: @ca - What I'm hinting at is the value of the two items ever true? Are you getting a race condition with another thread overwrites the values to something that it's correct? I ask this as you have p = worker later. Also are these stack variable? Are you blowing the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `finder` never increments above zero. Does it print finder = 0 at all? If it does, it means

```
memory[p+1] = Symtablelab[1]
```

just after 1st iteration, so the while loop gets terminated and `finder` sticks at 1.

**EDIT**
If you say, it prints `finder = 0` continuously inside the while statement, then probably you have `if (memory[p] == "J")` inside an outer `for` or `while` (looping) statement.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I should have made it more clear. When I `cout<<finder;` .. It is displayed over and over again and I have to ^C to exit the program because it's in an infinite loop. And it just displays zero.

Answer (score 1):

If it is continuously printing finder and it is 0, then I must ask if this whole code snippet you posted is enclosed in a while statement that you did not post. It makes absolutely no sense that the while loop included in the statement you posted would not be incrementing finder if it is the loop that gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Or the other possibility is that Symtablelab has overriden the '[' ']' operators. If neither of these things are true, that something incredibly wonky is going on.